# Unselectable Object in Outliner in 2.8

Tags: outliner

I've been fiddling with Blender 2.8, collections and parenting and I can't remember exactly how I was able to make this happen, but I have this empty object that has an animation that keeps affecting objects (which use it as a constraint) but can't be found anywhere in the "Scene" outliner, nor in the 3d view and isn't hidden and can't be selected or edited in any way!

The only place where I can see a reference to it is in the "Blender file" tab in the outliner as shown in the screenshot and the constraints dropdowns of other objects its affecting. Mouse clicks on this object in the outliner yields no effect... is this a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: You should upload the blend file so that people can take a closer look.

Comment: Seems like the *empty* object lives outside of any Scene. You can use the command line (python window) to link it to any scene or delete it.

Comment: As @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny said, you can check if the data is unlink in the properties panel with selecting view type from *View Layer* to *orphan data* in the header bar.

Comment: @Syler If you're going to suggest they upload a file, it's important you mention *where* they should upload it, e.g. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I wasnt able to upload the file. How can I do it through command line? Couldn't find docs ._.